# ROCR package... what am I not getting?

Tags: r, roc

I am testing a simple case using ROCR package in R.  Basically, here is my code.  I have a set of true values, and for each value, I have a set of predictions, and my labels are 1 if the prediction is within |2| of the true value, and 0 otherwise, like this:

```
  ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
  preds<-c(6,3,2,1,4)
  truevals<- c(8,4,2,1,7)
  df<-data.frame(ID, preds,truevals)
  df<- mutate(df, labels = ifelse(abs(df$preds - df$truevals) < 2, 1, 0))
  predtest<-prediction(df$preds, df$labels)
  auc <- performance(predtest, 'auc')
```

But my calculated AUC is 0, i.e.

```
> auc@y.values[[1]]
[1] 0
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong?  Clearly, some of the classifications are "correct", so why should the AUC be zero?  What am I not understanding?  My values are arranged by ID, i.e. I am assuming they are measurements of people with IDs 1 to 5.  Is there some ordering issue I'm not considering?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what's going on, draw a box plot of your data:

```
boxplot(preds ~ labels, data = df)
```

[image: Boxplot of predictions as a function of labels]

Notice how the predictions on the `0` class are *higher* than those of the `1` class.

Now look at the definition of the AUC from Wikipedia:

> [The AUC] is equal to the probability that a classifier will rank a
>   randomly chosen positive instance higher than a randomly chosen
>   negative one (assuming 'positive' ranks higher than 'negative'). [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve)

Now by convention, `1`s will usually be considered positives, and `0`s negatives. As we just saw, your `1`s, now the positives, rank *lower* than negatives (`0`s), so the probability that they are higher is 0.

You have 3 options:

A. If your `1`s are the negatives, ROCR has a `label.ordering` argument:

```
predtest <- prediction(df$preds, df$labels, label.ordering = c(1, 0))
auc <- performance(predtest, 'auc')
auc@y.values[[1]]
[1] 1
```

B. If your `1`s are indeed the positives, you can reverse your predictions so that positives are higher (notice the `-` sign in front of `df$labels`):

```
predtest <- prediction(df$preds, -df$labels)
auc <- performance(predtest, 'auc')
auc@y.values[[1]]
[1] 1
```

C. You could also reverse the definition of the AUC so that becomes the probability that a classifier will rank a randomly chosen positive instance *lower* than a randomly chosen negative one. `ROCR` doesn't support this but other packages do and might even choose this automatically for you.

In the end, what matters is not whether your AUC is above or below 0.5, but how far it is from the diagonal. If it is lower than 0.5, or "worse than random", you only need to reverse your interpretation to perform better than random.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is clearly separable. `pred` 1 to 3 go with `label` 1 and 4 and 6 go with label 0.

That should give you an AUC equal to 1, which is the same as an AUC of 0. It's just a matter of reference.

Here's an example:

```r
library(ROCR)
ID = c(1,2,3,4,5)
preds = c(6,3,2,1,4)
truevals = c(8,4,2,1,7)
df = data.frame(ID, preds,truevals)
df = mutate(df, labels = ifelse(abs(df$preds - df$truevals) < 2, 1, 0))
#Changing the labels is just a matter of reference
#the algorithm is oblivious to their meaning
df$labels = 1 - df$labels
predtest = prediction(df$preds, df$labels)
auc = performance(predtest, "auc")
```

Output:

```
> auc@yvalues[[1]]
[1] 1
```

Switching labels raise an issue regarding leakage though, but I suppose that's not within the scope of the question.

EDIT:
The AUC is a measure of separability, it's the probability you will rank a random positive instance higher than a random negative one. The ROC curve is simply x:1-Specificity and y:Sensitivity, given different threshold for classification on your predictor.

So, regarding:

> [...] if I have a an arbitrary set of values and a set of of predictions of
>   those values, how do I get an ROC curve? I'm really confused. I assume
>   the closer the prediction, the better? I'm just not sure how to do
>   this. I don't know how to assign classes to the true values. Don't
>   there need to be rankings of some sort???

You have a set of binary categorical data and also a continuous predictor. Now set a threshold in the predictor, classifying observations higher than that threshold one class or otherwise the other class. Measure Specificity and Sensitivity, and mark that point in your curve. Try other thresholds (there's a finite number of possibilities that change Sens and Spec) and plot those points in the curve. That's the ROC curve.

The AUC will be higher the more separated your classes are regarding the predictor. The more superimposed they are the lower the AUC.

Comment: Huh?  This is not helpful. When I plot the ROC curve, it is BELOW the diagonal. This can't be right.

Comment: But those labels are meant to signify whether the prediction is valid or not.... what if i did not have separable data?  How would this change?

Comment: 0.5 is the AUC of the no-discrimination line a.k.a. random chance prediction. That's the worst result.

Comment: I understand this.  What I don't get is the following: if I have a an arbitrary set of values and a set of of predictions of those values, how do I get an ROC curve?  I'm really confused. I assume the closer the prediction, the better? I'm just not sure how to do this. I don't know how to assign classes to the true values. Don't there need to be rankings of some sort???

Comment: Yes, for example: you are at the diagonal and you move the threshold and Sens doesn't change, but Spec diminishes, moving below the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Something seems off in doing a two-sided binary classification using absolute values as I have done. I think that is what is confusing me. Maybe doing this is invalid, since the predictor thresholding is ordered....? Any thoughts?