# ROC for predictions - how to define class labels

Tags: roc

I have a set of predictions from a model, and a set of true values of the observations, and I want to create an ROC.

The quality of the prediction (in absolute error terms) is independent of the magnitude of the prediction.  So I have a set of predictions (pred(1), pred(2), ..., pred(n)) and observations (obs(1), obs(2), ..., obs(n)).

Someone told me to create the elements of my binary classification vector label(i) as label(i) = ifelse(|obs(i) - pred(i)| < tol, 1, 0) and then calculate the AUC (tol is some respecified tolerance).  So for each prediction, if it is close to the corresponding observation, the corresponding label is 1, otherwise it is 0.

But I don't see how the suggested labeling is valid, as higher pred() values will not necessarily discriminate my binary classification, i.e. prediction values do not serve to "RANK" the quality of my predictions (i.e., a given threshold does not divide my data naturally).  Can someone please shed some light for me on what to do here? Is the suggestion given above a valid one? Or is an ROC inappropriate to use here?

Comment: Who told you to do that? It is certainly not ROC analysis... you'll want to use a correlation measure instead.

Comment: My gut says you're right.  A colleague did it.  Can I get more elaboration from you or someone else on why it's invalid to binarize based on the predictor?

Comment: *a colleague suggested it

Answer (score 0):

ROC analysis is defined for binary classification, where the observed labels can take two values (binary), and your predictions are any sort of numbers. There are extensions of ROC analysis to multi-class classification, but your question suggests that your observations are some sort of continuous measurement. You could binarize them (something like `label(i) = ifelse(obs(i) > someValue, 1, 0)`), but it would be invalid for the labels to depend on the classification: they must be some sort of truth that is independent on your classifier.

Alternatively if your observations are continuous, you should assess the quality of your predictions with a coefficient of correlation or a similar measure.

Comment: You are certain about this, that it is invalid to binarize based upon the classifier?

Comment: It looks like this poster did a similar binarization that you commented on but didn't mention it was invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37268167/3954614

Comment: @user85727 that wasn't the question there

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd like some more details.